# How to enable another intel xeon phi coprocessor?

Tags: xeon-phi

I have a server with one mic card (mic0), and it works well. Recently, I added another mic (mic1) on the same server. mic1 could be detected by `lspci`, but doesn't appear using `ifconfig`. How could I enable mic1 to make it work together with mic0?

Comment: Superuser would be a better site for this question.

Comment: Thanks, @CameronSkinner, I will move it now.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the second card, you also needed to go through the configuration steps for the card. So, if you haven't done so yet, start with 'micflash -update -device mic1 -smcbootloader' or 'micflash -update -device mic1', depending on whether this is a B or C stepping card then 'micctrl --initdefaults mic1' and whatever other micctrl commands you need to get the configuration to where you want it to be. You will want to specify the mic1 on each of the commands, so that you don't mess with your configuration for mic0. Although the MPSS developers would really prefer it if you did all the configuration through micctrl, if you have a very complex configuration or a large host file you don't want micctrl to modify or some such complication, you can (carefully) modify those files by hand, but you still need to add least run the micctrl --initdefaults.

Comment: Thanks very much, @froth, I will have a try later and tell you the result.

Comment: Hi, @froth, as you said, after I run the `micctrl --initdefaults` and `micflash -update -device mic1 ...`, I saw 'mic1' by `ifconfig`. And I also did other settings and tests following [http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/5079/readme.txt](http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/5079/readme.txt). Thanks again!